# Understanding Kafka Streams Checkpointing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand the idea behind Kafka Streams Checkpointing. Is it just a consumer side management of offset info? Or is there more to it? Any links explaining the details would be helpful.

Comment: By checkpoint, do you mean _offset_?

Comment: I am aware of the partition offset thats stored on the internal kafka topics (since > 0.9). I have seen some articles talking about Kafka Checkpointing; so I am trying to understand where it fits in the Kafka eco-system

Comment: Can you point to the articles you mention? Kafka does not really do checkpointing (Kafka Streams does as explained by Tuyen, but it's an implementation details and not really exposed to the users). It's unclear to me, what your question is about.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I am refering to Kafka Stream Checkpointing. Whats the need for checkpointing in general; Thats what I am trying to understand

Comment: RocksDB stores write data to local disk and the local checkpoint files store the corresponding changelog topic offsets. Thus, the checkpoint files are just metadata. They are used to "remember" what data are in the store. Each time RocksDB is flushed (including a flush of all pending writes to the changelog topic) the checkpoint file is updated accordingly with the lates changelog topic offsets.

Answer (score 4):

Checkpoint in Kafka Streams is used for storing offset of changelog topic of state store, so when application restarted and state restore is happened, a `restore consumer` will try to continue consume from this offset stored in checkpoint file if the offset is still valid, if not the restore process will remove the old state and start restore by consuming from the beginning of changelog topic.

I can't find anything about checkpoint in `Kafka Streams` document, [it was added from 1.1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6121).